# I'm having an issue inserting an if conditional w/in a jquery function

Tags: jquery, if-statement

```
$('#next').click(function() {
  var i = $("li.current").index();
    if(i<3){
      $('#li.current').removeClass('current');
          };

});
```

I can alert i but when I add that if statement, I can't get anything. The rest of my jquery is working so there doesn't seem to be anything broken per se but I must be thinking too hard or just too wrong.

I'm eventually thinking of adding .next() and adding the class back but if the above isn't working, I'd like to know why?

Answer (score 4):

You have an erroneous `#` here: `$('#li.current').removeClass('current');`

Remove it (and the extra `;` after the `if`) and you should be ok:

```
$('#next').click(function() {
    var i = $("li.current").index();
    if(i<3){
        $('li.current').removeClass('current');
    }
});
```

I assume you want the `li` element and not an element with `id="li"`.